# Best search python algorithm along tables

Tags: python, dataframe, search

I have three dataframes with common id's in them. I have to search for one condition in table1 (condition == 'legalizado) and if met, then take the value of the column id for that condition and find it in table2. After found, take the value of column 'Marca' in table 2 for that id and append it to  list_nombres.
If the condition is not met, then it should take the id and search for it in table 3 and retrieve the corresponding value of column 'Name' in table3 and append it to list_nombres.
This list_nombres will be a new column of table1.

I've tried with if and for loop, but it´s taking about two hours to complete and I really need to optimize this since data will continue to grow.
The tables look like this:

[image: table1]

[image: Table2]

[image: Table3]

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: pandas has the "merge" function to build a new dataframe from the first two. After sorting the new df by condition you can use the Series method "searchsorted" to efficiently find the relevant rows.

Answer (score 0):

Just like with a database, loops should be the last resort. In fact if you find yourself writing a loop, it's pretty much guaranteed you are doing something wrong.

Consider using [`.loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to apply a condition to `table1` and lookup values in `table2`:

```
table1 = pd.DataFrame([['6x123','legalizado'],['6x124','legalizado'],['6x125','estable']], columns=['id','condition'])
table2 = pd.DataFrame([['6x123','a'],['6x124','b'],['6x125','d']], columns=['id','Marca'])

df = table1.loc[table1['condition']=='estable', ['id']].merge(table2, on='id')
print(df)
```

With my fakey data, that spits out:

```
      id Marca
0  6x125     d
```

Using this approach, if you get more than one hit on `table1` with `loc()` it will merge all of those hits with `table2` and return every `Marca` that has an `id` that fits that description.

Comment: Thanks, this will do the first part. But what can be done with the values where the condition is not met and are found in table3?

Comment: I don't follow your logic well enough to say. You start by searching a `condition` in table1, look up the `id` found in table2 to get the `Marca`. But if the `condition` search yields nothing, then what `id` would you look up in `table3`?

Comment: the id corresponding to that value. In table1 I only have two id's that met the condition of 'Legalizado' Those two must be searched in table2 and get the corresponding value for that id in column Marca of table2, but the other two values do not meet the condition, so I must search them in table3 and get the value for that id of column Name in table3